# c# alternative to socket.io for node.js

Tags: c#, socket.io

Is there something like socket.io (node.js) for C# ? I need a server version of it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I do not think there is any framework in .NET which has evented IO support like node.js or ruby's EventMachine or python twisted :-(.

Comment: @kazimanzurrashid : Van Coding was asking of an equivalent to socket.io, not node.js...

Answer (score 29):

SignalR

Async signaling library for .NET to help build real-time, multi-user interactive web applications.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

You can see a live example of it in play here http://jabbr.net/

You will need IIS 8.0 to get web sockets, it uses long-polling on IIS 7.

I think they may be working on using https://github.com/davidfowl/Fleck and https://github.com/davidfowl/SignalR.Fleck to show how you can use Fleck web socket server with SignalR

Answer (score 8):

.NET has a number of ways to implement a 100% async design similar to node.js.

See [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5.aspx)'s [BeginSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9.aspx)/[EndSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f6fk8ze.aspx) and higher-performance [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync.aspx), or [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx)'s [BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx)/[BeginWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginwrite.aspx) methods.  These are all very similar to node.js.

C# 5.0 is bringing in a new async design with language support that will be a lot easier to use than those above.  You can play around with a beta of it in the [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360).

Comment: The delegates and new C# Async is not same as the framework I mentioned. Those frameworks uses a single non blocking thread on the other hand in .NET each client is handled by a separate thread and this is the fundamental difference.

Comment: Oops, I forgot that node.js uses a single thread.  However, .NET does not handle each client on a separate thread -- it uses a thread pool and never blocks.  If you lock when accessing global state you should be fine.  Also, the C# Async CTP uses whatever execution context you start the I/O in -- if your context is single-threaded, it will only use that single thread for all your connections.

Answer (score 4):

Just saw a video from mix11, where they talked about Manos de Mono.  It is a C# framework modeled after tornadoweb with inspiration from frameworks like node.js.

https://github.com/jacksonh/manos

Answer (score 3):

There is also another library called XSockets

http://xsockets.net/

They also include a fallback for browsers that don't implement the [WebSocket](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) protocol Fallback via Flash

Answer (score 0):

This has just been released, documentation and examples are on the way!

https://github.com/kayak/kayak
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kayak-http/LXS_xh0qurM

You may also want to check out
http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/

I'm not sure if it uses a single thread or thread-pool though.. But that will only be a problem once you want to have 1000s of connections at any one time.